# Can't get workspace project to reflect latest changes tfs visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

After using a "GetLatestVersion" to retreive my coworker's new project added to `Source Control`, we realized that the folder structure was incorrect. He deleted the issues on `Source Control` and everything looked great there. It runs on his end.

Unfortunately for me, even after running the "GetSpecificVersion" and checking all the overwrite boxes, I cannot get the new version of his project on my local workspace.

Ok.

How now do I delete the project on my end without TFS knowing (so I don't have to`CheckIn`anything and TFS doesn't think it needs to bring anything onto the server from my local workspace).

It makes most sense to me to:

```
- log out of Source Control, close the project and Visual Studio, 
- go into my workspace folder and delete the coworker's broken project
- log back into Source Control, bring up the workspace project in Solution Explorer, and re- "GetLatestVersion" and overwrite files.
```

Has anyone had this problem before? I'm working in VisualStudio 2012

Comment: Are you 100% positive that your co-worker did in fact check in all of his changes that "fixed" it? I would start by double checking that.

Comment: You are totally correct. It ended up being an issue with a file not being on source control but the reference still existing in the solution to an adjacent dll file on his workspace. So the Checkin worked (but shouldn't have! In my opinion...). Working with TFS has been so much more difficult than anticipated.

Comment: I guess I should delete this? I feel the comments are useful to others, perhaps.

Comment: I can add my comment as an answer?

Comment: Please do! Maybe add some additional info about Checking In if you have any to share.

Comment: @Rach Whether your project builds, or is even logically consistent, is not traditionally up to a version control tool to enforce.  If you want this, you should set up continuous integration builds and turn on gated check-in, which will prevent a check-in from proceeding if a build fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you 100% positive that your co-worker did in fact check in all of his changes that "fixed" it? I would start by double checking that. In team explorer, make certain that they do not have any files that need to be checked in under "Excluded Files".

If you have a TFS Build Server, make certain that the CI build (or you can manually run it) was successful. This will at least prove whether TFS has the project buildng correctly.

If you don't have a TFS build server, have another co-worker pull it down to verify that everything got checked in correctly.

If you are sure that they checked in everything ok and it is still not working for you, try pulling it down to a different directory. Also, you can manually delete your copy of the solution through file explorer and then pull it down again (with the overwrite checked).